# html response time java servlet is very high

Tags: java, html, json, tomcat, servlets

I have a servlet which needs to handle high volumes of simple http requests. I sometimes have to return it as an json response and the other times as html.

The code of the entire servlet is the same however at the end I have an if-statement:

```
 if(json) {
      request.setContentType("application/JSON");
      String json_response = String.format("some string %s", some_other_string);
      out.print(json_response);
 } else {
      request.setContentType("text/html");
      String html_response = String.format("<html><body>some text %s</body></html>", some_other_string);
      out.print(html_response);
 }
```

My connection pooling settings are:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/testdb"
auth="Container"
type="javax.sql.DataSource"
factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/table?autoReconnect=true"
username="user"
password="pass"
maxActive="250"
maxIdle="60"
minIdle="30"
maxWait="10000"
/>
```

I run it on a dedicated server. quad-core with 12gb ram and a ssd. Tomcat 8 and Sun jdk 8

When I send requests for json responses the server has no problem handeling 200 requests per second.
But when I send requests for html responses the response time is around 80 ms when the load is less then 10 requests per second, but when it goes over this the response time goes on average to 3000 - 4000 ms.

I timed the servlet execution and it is executed in 1ms. Also with the html response at high load, so the 3000 ms should come from somewhere else.

I tried putting the html into a jsp file but this did not change anything.

I was not able to get visualVM running to check the performance of the servlet but since it executes in 1ms I think the problem should be somewhere in the Tomcat config.

Does anybody have an idea on an approach to fixing this problem?

Thanks

Comment: How are you measuring response times?

Comment: @juan.facorro I use an http uptime monitor from Monitis (3rd party app). I also just checked the page itself, when I do json requests it loads instantly and with html it takes a couple of seconds (only under load).

Comment: Since there's not much information to be able to draw any conclusions, I would suggest using a simple tool like [ab](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html) to hit the endpoint while monitoring CPU usage on the server. If the CPU is high then do some profiling to find the bottleneck. Sorry I don't have more concrete suggestions.

Comment: @juan.facorro Oh yes off course I forgot to mention this very important detail. The cpu and memory usage is below 10%. So I have no idea why there is any problem at all.

Comment: @juan.facorro I run the ab tool: ab -n 100000 -c 200 "Hostname/path"
This is ApacheBench, Version 2.3 <$Revision: 655654 $>
Copyright 1996 Adam Twiss, Zeus Technology Ltd, http://www.zeustech.net/
Licensed to The Apache Software Foundation, http://www.apache.org/

Benchmarking hostname (be patient)
Completed 10000 requests
Completed 20000 requests
Completed 30000 requests
Completed 40000 requests
Completed 50000 requests
Completed 60000 requests
Completed 70000 requests
Completed 80000 requests
Completed 90000 requests
Completed 100000 requests
Finished 100000 requests

Comment: Server Port:            80
Document Path:          path
Document Length:        268 bytes
Concurrency Level:      200
Time taken for tests:   42.895 seconds
Complete requests:      100000
Failed requests:        469
   (Connect: 0, Receive: 0, Length: 469, Exceptions: 0)
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      41838339 bytes
HTML transferred:       26824989 bytes
Requests per second:    2331.28 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       85.790 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.429 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          952.51 [Kbytes/sec] received

Comment: Connection Times (ms)
              min  mean[+/-sd] median   max
Connect:        0   32  11.9     34    1007
Processing:    22   53 279.7     42   19940
Waiting:        6   45 279.9     35   19932
Total:         47   86 279.2     75   19950Percentage of the requests served within a certain time (ms)
  50%     75
  66%     78
  75%     81
  80%     84
  90%     92
  95%     96
  98%    102
  99%    111
 100%  19950 (longest request)

Comment: The cpu and memory usage looked allright, it peaked around 40% cpu. However I did see one strange peak for a process: lfd - (child) process tracking...

Comment: @juan.facorro I also tried testing the servlet from another server (same hosting provider, so I think it should be in the same warehouse). Now the server held up okay with 100000 request and 10 concurrency with the JSON and 100000 requests and 5 concurrency for the iframe requests. This corresponds with around 1k requests/sec. Do you have any idea where I can start looking for the error in the system? Thanks for your help.